# Retrieve value of variable from view to controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve a value from my view to controller.The value is generated at runtime.

```
<ng-option ng-repeat="w in details track by $index">
    <div class="program-grid-row table-row" >
      <div>
          <a class= ng-click="setWork('hello')" 
                  href="#/helloworls/{{w[5]}}">{{w[5]}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</ng-option>
```

I want to retrieve the value of w[5] at my controller such that
controller.js

```
$http.get(Url +$scope.w[5]).then(function(response){
  $rootScope.details= response.data;
});
```

Not sure how can we retrieve the value of w[5] at the controller. Pls help.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect and unclear. You are trying to get 6th element of `w` for all the iteration over `details` . and then what are you doing in `$http` get ? Doesnt make any sense. Do you want to make that `$http` call in `setWork` function ? so that a http request is made for the `clicked` `<a href>`

Comment: Check my answer where I have provided answer for both possibility

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get `w[5]` of the last value of `$scope.details` but I think your question is not correct in itself:

```
<ng-option ng-repeat="w in details track by $index">
<div class="program-grid-row table-row" >
  <div>
      <a class= ng-click="setWork('hello')" 
              href="#/helloworls/{{w[5]}}">{{myData = w[5]}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
</ng-option>
```

in controller

```
$http.get(Url +$scope.myData).then(function(response){
   $rootScope.details= response.data;
});
```

### OR

```
<ng-option ng-repeat="w in details track by $index">
<div class="program-grid-row table-row" >
  <div>
      <a class= ng-click="setWork(w[5])" 
              href="#/helloworls/{{w[5]}}">{{w[5]}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
</ng-option>
```

in controller

```
$scope.setWork = function(data){
   $http.get(Url +data).then(function(response){
      $rootScope.details= response.data;
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `w[5]` as a parameter in `ng-click` function and get that clicked value in the controller:

**VIEW**

```
<ng-option ng-repeat="w in details track by $index">
      <div class="program-grid-row table-row" >
      <div>
      <a class= ng-click="setWork(w[5])"
    href="#/helloworls/{{w[5]}}">{{w[5]}}</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</ng-option>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.setWork = function(param){
  //param has `w[5]` value which is clicked
  $http.get(Url + param).then(function(response){
    $rootScope.details= response.data;
  });
}
```

Comment: But my details has multiple rows.How will it switch automatically to the selected row and further to the fifth field of that row

Comment: @Pall did you ask how to retrieve the 5th value in controller? That is how you do it

Comment: @Pall check my updated answer that should surely work for you